# How to create a hierarchical structure with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am looking for a way to make it dynamic because the range of userlevels is wide.

Please help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2kN6E.gif)

Comment: Look at multi-index - https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the intent of the question is not clear, if you want to create a hierarchical index, you can achieve this in the following way

```
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(([21,22],[1,2,3,4,5],[60,70,80,90,100]), names=["uselevel","class","upper"])
pd.DataFrame(index=idx, columns=['column1','column2','column3'])

df.head(10)
            column1 column2 column3
uselevel    class   upper           
21  1   60  NaN NaN NaN
        70  NaN NaN NaN
        80  NaN NaN NaN
        90  NaN NaN NaN
       100  NaN NaN NaN
    2   60  NaN NaN NaN
        70  NaN NaN NaN
        80  NaN NaN NaN
        90  NaN NaN NaN
       100  NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: And replace `[21, 22]` with `range(from, to+1)`